# LINQ to EF returning all fields not just those in Select()

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

This is the gist of my query which I'm testing in LinqPad using Linq to Entity Framework.

In my mind the resultant SQL should begin with something like SELECT TableA.ID AS myID. Instead, the SELECT includes all fields from all of the tables. Needless to say this incurs a massive performance hit among other problems. How can I prevent this?

```
var AnswerList = this.Answers
                .Where(x=>
                    ..... various conditions on x and related entities...
                )
                .GroupBy(x => new {x.TableA,x.TableB,x.TableC})
                .Select(g=>new  {
                        myID = g.Key.TableA.ID,
                })


AnswerList.Dump();
```

In practice I'm using a new type instead of an anonymous one but the results are the same either way.

Let me know if you need me to fill in more of the ...'s.

**UPDATE**

I've noticed I can prevent this problem by explicitly specifying the fields I want returned in the GroupBy method, e.g. `new {x.TableA.ID ... }`

But I still don't understand why it doesn't work just using the Select method (which DOES work when doing the equivalent in Linq to SQL).

Comment: It's not possible. You are selecting only an anonymous object with Property `myID`.

Comment: Hi - maybe my question isn't clear - I'm trying to stop it from returning all the fields from the database. I just want myID but instead all the fields are returned AND THEN myID is extracted in memory.

Comment: Did you test in by SQL Server Management Studio Profiler? I tested a similar query and the most upper SELECT only returns one column.

Comment: Yes I did. I'm using LINQ to Entity Framework. If I use LINQ to SQL I get your results though.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi,**

Could you please try below....?

> ```
> var query = from SubCat in mySubCategory
>       where SubCat.CategoryID == 1
>       group 1 by SubCat.CategoryID into grouped
>       select new { Catg = grouped.Key,
>            Count = grouped.Count() };
> ```

**Thank you,
Vishal Patel**